# SaveFileDialog .net -- Overwriting read only files

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-xp, savefiledialog

I am creating an appliaction in Windows 7. I use a SaveFileDialog to let the user select where to save files.

In windows 7 if you select a read only file and try to overwrite you get a popup saying you cant. You then have to choose another file to overwrite or just create a new save.

The problem im having is that in Windows XP you dont get the popup message saying you cant save. Instead the program throws an exception.

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\spanish.xml' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings.CreateWriter(String outputFileName)
   at System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(String outputFileName, XmlWriterSettings settings)
   at TOOL.XMLExporter.export(TabControl& languageTabs, ProgressBar& progressBar1, Int32 selectedLanguage)
   at TOOL.Main.exportToXML()
   at TOOL.Main.toxmlToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

This is the code I call:

```
SaveFileDialog fldg = new SaveFileDialog();
            fldg.Title = "Save File";
            fldg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
            fldg.Filter = "(*.xml)|*.xml";
            fldg.FilterIndex = 2;
            fldg.RestoreDirectory = true;

        string path = "";

            if (fldg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                path = fldg.FileName;
            }
```

Is there a way to check if a file is read only and if so, display the same message(in xp).

Comment: And what is your intended behaviour?

Comment: @okrumnow "Is there a way to check if a file is read only and if so, display the same message(in xp)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call SaveFileDialog again:

```
bool foundFile = false;
SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();

while (!foundFile)
{
     if (dlg.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
        break;

     FileInfo info = new FileInfo(dlg.FileName);
     if (!info.IsReadOnly)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("File is readonly.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
     }
     else
     {
          foundFile = true;
     }
}
```

File is readonly ?

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(filename);
if(info.IsReadOnly)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Will this work if I am creating a new file also? I gather filename is something that exists. What if it doesnt?

Comment: If it not exist, .IsReadOnly returns true. (You can check this also with .Exists )

Comment: One other problem is to get the 'filename' you need the dialog to close. But it never does, as the exception is thrown before.